# RelativeLayout layout_above crashing app

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

--UPDATE-- April 17th, 2012

It seems that it is only crashing when I add:

```
        android:layout_above="@+id/lakeSearchAdWebView"
```

to lakeSearchScrollView, adding it to just lakeSearchDetailsWebView works fine.

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/lakeSearchScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="0dp"
            android:layout_y="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/contentbg" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchBar"
            android:layout_width="274dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="83dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/lakeSearchSearchBTN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/searchBar"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchBar"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Search" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/resultsTableLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lakeSearchSearchBTN" >
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/lakeSearchDetailsWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/lakeSearchAdWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to have lakeSearchScrollView and lakeSearchDetailsWebView setup so that they are always above lakeSearchAdWebview, so lakeSearchAdWebview is always visible. Only ONE of lakeSearchScrollView and lakeSearchDetailsWebView is visible at a time, that's whey they're setup to be sitting on top of eachother.

If I add the following line to lakeSearchScrollView, the apps crashes:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/lakeSearchAdWebView"
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm still quite new to Android so I'm thinking it's probably a newbie mistake... thanks in advance!

--UPDATE-- Source Code:

```
package com.theappdoor.ifish;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.util.Log;

public class iFishLakeSearch extends Activity {

    private EditText searchBar;
    private TableLayout resultsTableLayout;
    private DataHelper dh;
    private iFishLakeDetails iFishLD;

    private Button lakeSearchBTN;
    private ScrollView searchScrollView;
    private WebView detailsWebView;
    private String lake_id;

    private WebView lakeSearchAdWebView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setContentView(R.layout.lakesearch);
        //This sets the context to the be of the parent, which is what we want
        View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.lakesearch, null);
        setContentView(viewToLoad);

        //setup vars

        this.dh = new DataHelper(this);
        this.iFishLD = new iFishLakeDetails(this);

        // connect our elements from the UI XML

        this.searchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBar); //LINE 61

        this.resultsTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.resultsTableLayout);

        this.lakeSearchBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lakeSearchSearchBTN);
        this.lakeSearchBTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                lakeSearch(v);
            }
        });


        this.searchScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.lakeSearchScrollView);

        this.detailsWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.lakeSearchDetailsWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = this.detailsWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.detailsWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        this.detailsWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

        this.detailsWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webassets/index.html");

        this.lakeSearchAdWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.lakeSearchAdWebView);
        webSettings = this.lakeSearchAdWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        this.lakeSearchAdWebView.loadUrl(this.getString(R.string.server)+"/iFish_ads/");

    }
```

Line 61:

```
this.searchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
```

--UPDATE--

Crash Log:

```
    04-16 13:22:23.951: D/AndroidRuntime(20896): Shutting down VM
    04-16 13:22:23.951: W/dalvikvm(20896): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2154)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2149)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    ... 11 more
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.theappdoor.ifish/com.theappdoor.ifish.TabGroup2Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.theappdoor.ifish/com.theappdoor.ifish.iFishLakeSearch}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.webkit.WebView
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1491)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:657)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:329)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at com.theappdoor.ifish.iFishHome.goToLakeSearch(iFishHome.java:20)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    ... 14 more
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.theappdoor.ifish/com.theappdoor.ifish.iFishLakeSearch}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.webkit.WebView
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1491)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at com.theappdoor.ifish.TabGroupActivity.startChildActivity(TabGroupActivity.java:116)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at com.theappdoor.ifish.TabGroup2Activity.onCreate(TabGroup2Activity.java:10)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    ... 20 more
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.webkit.WebView
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at com.theappdoor.ifish.iFishLakeSearch.onCreate(iFishLakeSearch.java:61)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    04-16 13:22:23.970: E/AndroidRuntime(20896):    ... 27 more
    04-16 13:22:44.244: I/Process(20896): Sending signal. PID: 20896 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post line 20 from com.theappdoor.ifish.iFishLakeSearch.

Comment: Maybe the line 61 at iFishLakeSearch.java. How do you make the findViewById for the WebView?

Comment: You should post your source code, parts which are mentioned in log.

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_above="@+id/lakeSearchAdWebView" means the view will be directly above lakeSearchAdWebView. Since you stated you put that in two different views, there is a problem, since they cannot both be directly above lakeSearchAdWebView.

Therefore to fix, simply put:
`android:layout_above="@+id/lakeSearchAdWebView"` in the lakeSearchDetailsWebView

and then put `android:layout_above:"@+id/lakeSearchDetailsWebView"` in the lakeSearchScrollView

Doing it this way will have your views in the order (from top to bottom) lakeSearchScrollView, lakeSearchDetailsWebView,  lakeSearchAdWebView

Comment: Any view can align itself above another view, same for bottom. If there are multiple views, supplying such attribute, they'll be obscuring each other.

Comment: I want both lakeSearchDetailsWebView and lakeSearchScrollView to be above the lakeSearchAdWebView, because only 1 of the 2 are visible at any given time, the lakeSearchAdWebView is ALWAYS visible

Comment: So, what's your problem? question was about crashing app

Comment: Well, when I add android:layout_above="@+id/lakeSearchAdWebView" on lakeSearchDetailsWebView and lakeSearchScrollView the app crashes with the log I posted above